# Performance testing tool for Qt, Pyside desktop application

Tags: python, load-testing, pyside, performance-testing

I am developing a desktop application using Qt (Pyside) and Python.

I want to test performance of application, I search for performance testing tool but didn't find any tool.

Please suggest any good open souce or free desktop application performance testing tool.

Comment: You can just profile you application no matter has it GUI or not. See [profiling Python](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) and handy tool for [converting profile data to HTML format](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2html/)